# Take off {} using Position []

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation

Please consider :

```
 subIDs = {"AK6", "CF11", "CL4", "FC21", "MK5"};

 subColors = {LightOrange, LightBlue, LightYellow, LightGreen, LightRed}

 Graphics[{subColors[[Flatten@Position[subIDs, #, 3]]],Rectangle[]}]&/@subIDs
```

[image]

How could i avoid the output of position to be 1 for example instead of {1} which seems to be my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a parameter to `Position` so it returns only one result and apply `First` or `Part`as needed

```
subIDs = {"AK6", "CF11", "CL4", "FC21", "MK5"};

subColors = {LightOrange, LightBlue, LightYellow, LightGreen, LightRed}

Graphics[{subColors[[Position[subIDs, #, 3, 1][[1, 1]]]], 
    Rectangle[]}] & /@ subIDs
```

Furthermore, you could also use `Extract` that's more suited to `Position`'s output

```
subIDs = {"AK6", "CF11", "CL4", "FC21", "MK5"};

subColors = {LightOrange, LightBlue, LightYellow, LightGreen, LightRed}

Graphics[{First@Extract[subColors, Position[subIDs, #, 3, 1]], 
    Rectangle[]}] & /@ subIDs
```

Answer (score 7):

Does it have to be `Position`? To solve your example problem, a pattern-based solution may be easier:

```
subIDs = {"AK6", "CF11", "CL4", "FC21", "MK5"};
subColors = {LightOrange, LightBlue, LightYellow, LightGreen, LightRed};
pattern = Thread[subIDs -> subColors]
```

> ```
> {"AK6" -> RGBColor[1, 0.9, 0.8], "CF11" -> RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1], "CL4" -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.85], "FC21" -> RGBColor[0.88, 1, 0.88], "MK5" -> RGBColor[1, 0.85, 0.85]}
> ```

```
Graphics[{# /. pattern, Rectangle[]}] & /@ subIDs
```

> [image]

Comment: it was for position because I could not find other tricks. Your solution opens new door for me. THank You !

Answer (score 7):

Why not

```
  Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}] & /@ subColors
```

Or, perhaps, more generally,

```
  GraphicsRow@MapThread[Graphics[{#1, Rectangle[], Black, 
  Inset[Text@#2, {.5, .5}]}] &,  {subColors, subIDs}]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Others have shown you better ways to solve your example problem. Just in case your example was just made up to learn how to do what your title says I think `Sequence` is what you are after:

```
Graphics[{
  subColors[[Sequence @@ Flatten@Position[subIDs, #, 3]]],Rectangle[]
}] & /@ subIDs
```

`@@` is the short form of `Apply` which lets you exchange the head of an expression.