# How to use the value returned from Position as index for another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, index

say, I want to find an index of a specific element in a list using

```
Position[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, c]
```

and it returns `{{3}}`

How can I use this returned value as index to pick a certain element from another list? How can I convert `{{3}}` to an integer or is there any other way to achieve what I want to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [(1508)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/121), [(21966)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21966/121)

Comment: Another possibility is `PositionIndex` with `Part`. For example: `PositionIndex[list1][c] // list2[[#]] &`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you put your cursor on the `Position` command and press F1 for help, you will see the following under Properties and Relations: "Use Extract to extract parts based on results from Position." There is also an example. For your case:

```
p = Position[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, c]
Extract[list,p]
```

where list is the list you want to extract from.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Should have looked the docs up more closely.

Comment: `F1` is your friend.